# Unparseable date: "30-Jun-12"

Tags: java, date

I'm using a Java method to convert the date into suitable format:

```
private Timestamp toTimeStamp(String s) throws java.text.ParseException
    {
        Timestamp ts = null;
        java.util.Date date = null;
        if (s == null || s.trim().isEmpty()) return ts;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
        date = (java.util.Date) sdf.parse(s);
        ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

        return ts;

    }
```

When I tried to execute the form I get this error:

```
Unparseable date: "30-Jun-12"
```

I tried to change the the date format but I still get this error. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: wow, you scared me. I thought it's 30 June, today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. Your date format pattern is wrong. The `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S` can never match `30-Jun-12`. You need `dd-MMM-yy`. See also [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
2. When parsing day/month names, make sure that you specify the right locale matching the language used in the day/month names. Your system default locale seems to be not English at all.

So this should do:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = sdf.parse("30-Jun-12");
```

A third problem, which is actually more a design matter, you should not be using `java.sql.Timestamp` (and other SQL specific date types) anywhere in your model/business layer (you originally tagged the question JSF). You should only use it in your data layer. Use `java.util.Date` instead and convert only at exactly the moment you need to persist it in the DB like so

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Comment: "Your system default locale seems to be not English at all." - that was exactly my problem! Thanks for saving a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing date in format `30-Jun-12` then you should use format

```
dd-MMM-yy
```

with `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: I tested it, but it's not working. Maybe the reason is Oracle?

Comment: I think that the problem in the Java method `toTimeStamp` - the date from the javascript cannot be parsed

Answer (score 0):

If you develop web application and you run it in browser, try change preferable language settings in browser settings. Different countries have different date format, there is major difference between European Countries and United States, so try in your browser (eg. Firefox):

```
Tools => Options => Content => Choose preferable language
```

Make sure when you make your application focused in browser that language bar on the taskbar shows desirable langage.

If web application is not case:
Check regional setting and preferable language settings.