# How to get elements from Java ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a basic question. I have this ArrayList:

```
@Named("AccountProfileController")
@ViewScoped
public class AccountProfile implements Serializable
{

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;
    private int id;

    // Constructor
    public AccountProfile()
    {
        // get the ID value 
        try
        {
            this.id = Integer.parseInt((String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.id = 0;
        }
    }
    // Create List to store user data
    public ArrayList<userdata> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public class userdata
    {

        int userid;
        int groupid;
        String specialnumber;
        String username;
        String passwd;
        Date datetochangepasswd;
        String address;
        String stateregion;
        String country;
        String userstatus;
        String telephone;
        Date dateuseradded;
        Date userexpiredate;
        Date dateuserlocked;
        String city;
        String email;
        String description;

        public userdata(int userid, int groupid, String specialnumber, String username, String passwd, Date datetochangepasswd,
                String address, String stateregion, String country, String userstatus, String telephone, Date dateuseradded,
                Date userexpiredate, Date dateuserlocked, String city, String email, String description)
        {

            this.userid = userid;
            this.groupid = groupid;
            this.specialnumber = specialnumber;
            this.username = username;
            this.passwd = passwd;
            this.datetochangepasswd = datetochangepasswd;
            this.address = address;
            this.stateregion = stateregion;
            this.country = country;
            this.userstatus = userstatus;
            this.telephone = telephone;
            this.dateuseradded = dateuseradded;
            this.userexpiredate = userexpiredate;
            this.dateuserlocked = dateuserlocked;
            this.city = city;
            this.email = email;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getAddress()
        {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address)
        {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getCity()
        {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city)
        {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getCountry()
        {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country)
        {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public Date getDatetochangepasswd()
        {
            return datetochangepasswd;
        }

        public void setDatetochangepasswd(Date datetochangepasswd)
        {
            this.datetochangepasswd = datetochangepasswd;
        }

        public Date getDateuseradded()
        {
            return dateuseradded;
        }

        public void setDateuseradded(Date dateuseradded)
        {
            this.dateuseradded = dateuseradded;
        }

        public Date getDateuserlocked()
        {
            return dateuserlocked;
        }

        public void setDateuserlocked(Date dateuserlocked)
        {
            this.dateuserlocked = dateuserlocked;
        }

        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description)
        {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getEmail()
        {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email)
        {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public int getGroupid()
        {
            return groupid;
        }

        public void setGroupid(int groupid)
        {
            this.groupid = groupid;
        }

        public String getPasswd()
        {
            return passwd;
        }

        public void setPasswd(String passwd)
        {
            this.passwd = passwd;
        }

        public String getSpecialnumber()
        {
            return specialnumber;
        }

        public void setSpecialnumber(String specialnumber)
        {
            this.specialnumber = specialnumber;
        }

        public String getStateregion()
        {
            return stateregion;
        }

        public void setStateregion(String stateregion)
        {
            this.stateregion = stateregion;
        }

        public String getTelephone()
        {
            return telephone;
        }

        public void setTelephone(String telephone)
        {
            this.telephone = telephone;
        }

        public Date getUserexpiredate()
        {
            return userexpiredate;
        }

        public void setUserexpiredate(Date userexpiredate)
        {
            this.userexpiredate = userexpiredate;
        }

        public int getUserid()
        {
            return userid;
        }

        public void setUserid(int userid)
        {
            this.userid = userid;
        }

        public String getUsername()
        {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username)
        {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getUserstatus()
        {
            return userstatus;
        }

        public void setUserstatus(String userstatus)
        {
            this.userstatus = userstatus;
        }
    }

    // Getter for the data list
    public ArrayList<userdata> getuserdata()
    {

        return dataList;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initData() throws SQLException
    {
        //     settingsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if (ds == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
        }
        // Initialize a connection to Oracle
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        if (conn == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
        }
        // With SQL statement get all settings and values
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from USERS where USERID = ?");
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        try
        {
            //get data from database        
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
            while (result.next())
            {
                // Put the the data from Oracle into Array List

                dataList.add(new userdata(result.getInt("USERID"),
                        result.getInt("GROUPID"),
                        result.getString("SPECIALNUMBER"),
                        result.getString("USERNAME"),
                        result.getString("PASSWD"),
                        toDate(result.getString("DATETOCHANGEPASSWD")),
                        result.getString("ADDRESS"),
                        result.getString("STATEREGION"),
                        result.getString("COUNTRY"),
                        result.getString("USERSTATUS"),
                        result.getString("TELEPHONE"),
                        toDate(result.getString("DATEUSERADDED")),
                        toDate(result.getString("USEREXPIREDATE")),
                        toDate(result.getString("DATEUSERLOCKED")),
                        result.getString("CITY"),
                        result.getString("EMAIL"),
                        result.getString("DESCRIPTION")));

            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
    // Call Crypto library for password convert into SHA hash
    @Inject
    @OSGiService(dynamic = true, waitTimeout = 5)
    transient CryptoSHA SHA;

    // Convert Password String into SHA hash
    public String passwdConvert(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        return SHA.ShaEncryptHash(password);
    }

    // Insert the data into Oracle
    public void saveData() throws SQLException, java.text.ParseException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {

        String SqlStatement = null;

        if (ds == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try
        {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
            try
            {           /*
                 * insert into Oracle the default system(Linux) time
                 */


                SqlStatement = "UPDATE USERS "
                        + "SET "
                        + "USERID = ?, "
                        + "GROUPID = ?, "
                        + "SPECIALNUMBER = ?, "
                        + "USERNAME = ?, "
                        + "PASSWD = ?, "
                        + "DATETOCHANGEPASSWD = ?, "
                        + "ADDRESS = ?, "
                        + "STATEREGION = ?, "
                        + "COUNTRY = ?, "
                        + "USERSTATUS = ?, "
                        + "TELEPHONE = ?, "
                        + "DATEUSERADDED = ?, "
                        + "USEREXPIREDATE = ?, "
                        + "DATEUSERLOCKED = ?, "
                        + "CITY = ?, "
                        + "EMAIL = ?, "
                        + "DESCRIPTION = ? "
                        + "WHERE USERID = " + id;

                ps = conn.prepareStatement(SqlStatement);

                ps.setInt(1, dataList.get(userid));
                ps.setInt(2, dataList.get(groupid));
                ps.setString(3, dataList.get(specialnumber));
                ps.setString(4, dataList.get(username));
                ps.setString(5, passwdConvert(dataList.get(passwd)));
                ps.setDate(6, toDate(dataList.get(datetochangepasswd)));
                ps.setString(7, dataList.get(address));
                ps.setString(8, dataList.get(stateregion));
                ps.setString(9, dataList.get(country));
                ps.setString(10, dataList.get(userstatus));
                ps.setString(11, dataList.get(telephone));
                ps.setDate(12, toDate(dataList.get(dateuseradded)));
                ps.setDate(13, toDate(dataList.get(userexpiredate)));
                ps.setDate(14, toDate(dataList.get(dateuserlocked)));
                ps.setString(15, dataList.get(city));
                ps.setString(16, dataList.get(email));
                ps.setString(17, dataList.get(description));


                ps.executeUpdate();

                conn.commit();
                committed = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!committed)
                {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            /*
             * Release the resources
             */
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

    }
    //!!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135675/unparseable-date-30-jun-12
    // Convert the Date format

    public Date toDate(String s)
    {
        Date d = null;
        if (s == null || s.trim().isEmpty())
        {
            return d;
        }

        try
        {
            d = Date.valueOf(s);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }

        return d;
    }
}
```

I tried to get the elements using this Java code:

```
ps.setInt(1, dataList.get(userid));
ps.setInt(2, dataList.get(groupid));
ps.setString(3, dataList.get(specialnumber));
ps.setString(4, dataList.get(username));
ps.setString(5, passwdConvert(dataList.get(passwd)));
ps.setDate(6, toDate(dataList.get(datetochangepasswd)));
ps.setString(7, dataList.get(address));
ps.setString(8, dataList.get(stateregion));
ps.setString(9, dataList.get(country));
ps.setString(10, dataList.get(userstatus));
ps.setString(11, dataList.get(telephone));
ps.setDate(12, toDate(dataList.get(dateuseradded)));
ps.setDate(13, toDate(dataList.get(userexpiredate)));
ps.setDate(14, toDate(dataList.get(dateuserlocked)));
ps.setString(15, dataList.get(city));
ps.setString(16, dataList.get(email));
ps.setString(17, dataList.get(description));
```

But I get error in Netbeans. Can you tell me what is the proper way to get the elements from the ArrayList?

Best Wishes

Comment: Who said that Java is verbose ?

Comment: Who said that this was a good way to use Java?

Comment: I'm new to Java. Would you explain me where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is `ps`? An `ArrayList<userdata>`?

Comment: I think you may need to specify what your goal with this code is to make it easier to answer.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Is it the constructor with 17 parameters that makes you say that? ;-)

Comment: I added the complete source code.

Comment: doesn't really matter what ps is, he's asking how to access the members of the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Using `for-each loop this is optimize way...`**

```
for(userdata obj : dataList){

   System.out.println("User ID :: " + obj.userid);
   System.out.println("Group ID :: " + obj.groupid);
   .
   .
   .

}
```

**Using for loop**

```
for(int i =0;i<datalist.size();i++){

       userdate obj=datalist.get(i);
       System.out.println("User ID :: " + obj.userid);
       System.out.println("Group ID :: " + obj.groupid);
       .
       .
       .

    }
```

Comment: I would just add using the the getter methods, as depending on where he is iterating over the list, it may not work the way you have it.

Answer (score 5):

```
ArrayList<userdata> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.add(new userdata(...)); // The ... is for all your params
userdata data = dataList.get(0); // This gets the first element of the list, the one we just added
System.out.println(data.getCity()); // This will print the String called city
```

A side note, userdata should be UserData, it is a Java convention to use uppercase for the first letter of any classes you define.

Edited:

I see what you are trying to do now, you will want to change your insert to be more like the following:

```
for (userdata data : dataList) {
    ps.setInt(1, data.getUserid());
    ps.setInt(2, data.getGroupid());
    ...
}
```

Also you will need to perform inserts for new items, and updates for old items.

Answer (score 3):

```
ps.setInt(1, dataList.get(i).getUserId());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your object dataList contains objects of type userData (should be UserData, by the way).

When you call `dataList.get(something)`, that something should be an integer value, and the `get` method retrieves the object at that position.

If want to fill up the PreparedStatement with the first object in your list, what you would do is:

```
UserData user = dataList.get(0);
ps.setInt(1, user.getUserId())
...
```

If you want to do the same for every user:

```
for(userdata obj : dataList){

    ps.setInt(1, obj.userid);
    ...

    //do something with PS for this object.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for(userdata datum : dataList)
{ //for each userdata instance in dataList collection
            ps.setInt(1, datum.userid); //ps.setInt(1, datum.getUserid());
            ps.setInt(2, datum.groupid);
            ps.setString(3, datum.specialnumber);
            //... you get the idea
}
```

basically, you need to get your userdata item from the list using the dataList.get(index) and then pull out your fields from the instance of the userdata.

kinda like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++)
{
            ps.setInt(1, dataList.get(i).getUserid()); //ps.setInt(1, datum.getUserid());
            ps.setInt(2, dataList.get(i).getGroupId());
            ps.setString(3, dataList.get(i).specialnumber);
            //... you get the idea
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to update every item in you list you need to loop through each item and execute them indidually.

```
 public void saveData() throws SQLException, java.text.ParseException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String SqlStatement = null;
    if (ds == null) {
        throw new SQLException();
    }

    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    if (conn == null) {
        throw new SQLException();
    }

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        boolean committed = false;
            //removed the userid as that is used in the where to determine what record to update
            //so it will be the same
            SqlStatement = "UPDATE USERS "
                    + "SET "
                    + "GROUPID = ?, "
                    + "SPECIALNUMBER = ?, "
                    + "USERNAME = ?, "
                    + "PASSWD = ?, "
                    + "DATETOCHANGEPASSWD = ?, "
                    + "ADDRESS = ?, "
                    + "STATEREGION = ?, "
                    + "COUNTRY = ?, "
                    + "USERSTATUS = ?, "
                    + "TELEPHONE = ?, "
                    + "DATEUSERADDED = ?, "
                    + "USEREXPIREDATE = ?, "
                    + "DATEUSERLOCKED = ?, "
                    + "CITY = ?, "
                    + "EMAIL = ?, "
                    + "DESCRIPTION = ? "
                    + "WHERE USERID = " + ?; //also changed this to be a parameter

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(SqlStatement);

            for (userdata data: datalist) {
              ps.setInt(1, dataList.getGroupid());
              ps.setString(2, dataList.getSpecialnumber());
              ...
              //continue setting the others variables
              //the last on will be the userid in the where clause
              ps.setInt(17, dataList.getUserId());
              //execute the update
              ps.executeUpdate();
            }
            //now we commit since they have all ran. We want an all or nothing update
            //meaning if one fails, nothing is updated
            conn.commit();
            committed = true;

    }
    finally
    { 
        if (!committed){
          conn.rollback();
        }
        ps.close();
        conn.close();
    }

}
```

I also consolidated the finally blocks, as there is no reason to have two in this case.