# Java/Groovy - simple date reformatting

Tags: java, date, groovy, reformat

I'm new to Java/Groovy development and I have a simple string that I would like to reformat, however I get an 'Unparseable date' error when I attempt to run the following:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 
import java.util.Date

String oldDate
Date date
String newDate 

oldDate = '04-DEC-2012'
date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(oldDate)
newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("M-d-yyyy").format(date) 

println newDate
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but the solution eludes me.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Your date is given in "DD-MMM-YYYY" pattern, and you are trying to parse something else...

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135675/unparseable-date-30-jun-12

Comment: Not knowing Grrovy for new readers to this question I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate`, `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and  `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [this answer by user7605325](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645976/5772882).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

With Groovy, you don't need the includes, and can just do:

```
String oldDate = '04-DEC-2012'
Date date = Date.parse( 'dd-MMM-yyyy', oldDate )
String newDate = date.format( 'M-d-yyyy' )

println newDate
```

To print:

```
12-4-2012
```

Comment: @Andreas 7 years later, the link is http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.4/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4):

Your `DateFormat` pattern does not match you input date `String`. You could use

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

`oldDate` is not in the format of the `SimpleDateFormat` you are using to parse it.

Try this format: `dd-MMM-yyyy`  - It matches what you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Groovy Script

import java.util.Date   
import java.util.TimeZone   
tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo")   
def date = new Date()   
def dt = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone=tz)   
println dt //formatado   
println date // formatado porém, horario do Sistema em GMT.
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also and quite importantly, in what way does your answer answer the question? I believe the question was about reformatting from a format like `04-DEC-2012` into `12-4-2012`.

Comment: @OleV.V. How would the OPs problem be solved with java.time? Do you have an example?

Comment: In Java: Parse `oldDate` from the qusetion using [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66680435/5772882), only the pattern needs to be `dd-MMM-uuuu` (four digit year). For formatting the `LocalDate` from that answer into `12-4-2012`, use `date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M-d-u"))`.

Comment: Olá @OleV.V., realmente descrevi minha resposta de maneira errada, agradeço as suas dicas.